# Tensorflow: tf.reverse_sequence - seq_dim and batch_dim

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to learn Tensorflow and was looking at `tf.reverse_sequence`. It has two parameters `seq_dim` and `batch_dim`. From the documentation given [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reverse_sequence) I understand that setting `batch_dim = 0` means we go through the the rows from top and setting `seq_dim = 1` means we go through columns from left to right but what do these numbers mean? I can't understand from the documentation when I should set `batch_dim = 1` or `2`. I tried `reverse_sequence` on `x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]` and got `[[3,2,1], [6,5,4], [9,8,7]]` with `batch_dim = 0` and `seq_dim = 1`. But I always get errors when I change `seq_dim` and `batch_dim` values from `1` and `0` respectively. Could someone explain the meaning of these values?